# QextserialPort 1.2 win-alpha build error

Tags: qt4

I'm new to QT.

Hi,  I got to know QextSerialPort 1.2-win-Alpha API is useful to develop a serial communication application, so I downloaded and started to build.

However, it is raising an error dialog , "Coudn't find executable, Specify at least one" when pressing the Executable Browsing button.

If I just use cancel button in the dialog appeared i could get qextserialport-build-desktop

Thanks for the quick response...

I am guessing that the problem is some missing header files

I could see in posix_qextserialport.h file that

```
#include "termios.h"
#include "sys/ioctl.h"
#include "sys/select.h"
```

are underlined with wavy green line

and the build log shows as below Starting ...

*The process could not be started!*

The above error is same even for QSerialDevice

I dont know how to add the header files/library to QT4... Can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Deducing from the name, you have an older copy from sourceforge. AFAIK the project has moved to http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/ a while ago (although development has stalled there, too, apparently).
Try fetching the latest version of the code from the google code repo and compiling it. It is more likely to work.

PS. A build log would be of great use in this kind of case. Even if You can't decipher it Yourself, somebody else may do it for You. ;)